# Log4j. ver. 1.2.12. Change filename pattern in rolling policy

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, configuration-files

So far when log4j backups old log file it renames it to smth. like this "creation date"."counter".log. How can i make it back up in the following way: "creation date"-"creation time".log? I mean how to embed creation time (hours & minutes) into the saved log file name? Below it the part of my log4j cfg.file:

```
<appender name="TCPIP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logDir}/radius.log</file>
    <append>true</append>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- Only errors will be written to this file -->
        <level>WARNING</level>
    </filter>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${logDir}/tcpip/%d.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${maxHistory}</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>${maxFileSize}</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: If you do not use log4j2, why its tag does appear? Pls remove.

Comment: You are using logback.